# Execute a SQL command before Entity Framework commands, in the same connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC application accessing an existing database through EF code first. The database is from an already existing system, and I can't change its structure or code, just insert records.

So I have a `DbContext` object to save to entities:

```
using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
{ 
    MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
    e.MyProperty = "value";
    db.MyEntity.Add(e);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is that the `MyEntity` table has a trigger that requires `SET DATEFORMAT MDY` to be run so it works.

So that's my question: how do I execute this command before calling `SaveChanges` to apply its generated commands? I've tried

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("set dateformat mdy");
```

but it didn't work, Its probably using a different connection.

Another alternative would be setting this parameter at the connection string, if possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to explicitly use a `Connection` object to do this. By default, EF performs an Open / DoStuff / Close connection process. If you use a Connection object, the connection (and thus stuff you set for the connection) persists.

Comment: You can set a default language for the login you use that would assume the required dateformat, for example `alter login [SVC_MyApp] with default_language = [us_english];`. If the opposite isn't required by some other part of the application, that is.

Answer (score 0):

As @Laughing Vergil notes, you can access the connection object before your DbContext runs queries.  If you ca `db.Database.Connection.Open()` EF6 or `db.Database.OpenConnection()` in EF Core, the connection will remain open for the lifetime of your DbContext.  And so you can set connection properties, use ADO.NET directly on the Connection, etc.

You can do this in your DbContext constructor to make it a global behavior, or for a particular method, like this:

```
using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
{ 
    db.Database.Connection.Open(); //EF6
    //db.Database.OpenConnection(); //EF Core
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("set dateformat mdy");

    MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
    e.MyProperty = "value";
    db.MyEntity.Add(e);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```